# NoClassDefFoundError - could not initialize class ...?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am getting an error while writing my simple test program:

```
package Xbee;

import com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBee;
import com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBeeException;

public class XbeeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        XBee xbee = new XBee();

        try {
            xbee.open("COM22", 9600);
        } catch (XBeeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am getting the following:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.RXTXVersion
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.RxTxSerialComm.openSerialPort(RxTxSerialComm.java:71)
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.RxTxSerialComm.openSerialPort(RxTxSerialComm.java:61)
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBee.open(XBee.java:140)
    at Xbee.XbeeTest.main(XbeeTest.java:14)
```

The whole problem is that it cannot initialize the class gnu.io.RXTXversion, which is a prt of rtxtcomm.jar, which I have included in my Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bidib.jbidib.org.qbang.rxtx</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxtxcomm</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: class gnu.io.RXTXversion, which is a prt of rtxtcomm.jar ,, it mean this class exist in this jar ??

Comment: yeah, it means that .. I made a typo

Comment: I think you need some native library, too. Something like librxtxSerial.so or rxtxSerial.dll depends of you OS

Comment: class : gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver contain one line as (RXTXVersion.loadLibrary("rxtxSerial");) and exception (no rxtxSerial in java.library.path) seems that some library is missing containing rxtxSerial as class

Answer (score 3):

As I previously mention in comment, you need also native library to make it work. Put it in ${JRE_HOME}/lib/i386

nice article: http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Access_Your_Serial_Port_using_Java

and quote from article:

> $ wget http://rxtx.qbang.org/pub/rxtx/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip
>
> Unzip the rxtx archive and install it. The following commands assume
> your JVM is located in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/ and that you are
> using a 32-bit x86 computer. You will need to slightly modify these
> commands if you have a different JVM or system architecture (i.e.,
> 64-bit).
>
> $ sudo apt-get install zip
>
> $ unzip rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip
>
> $ cd rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2
>
> $ sudo cp RXTXcomm.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/
>
> $ sudo cp Linux/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtx* /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/

Comment: I skipped the last one, but now it works. However, in the /jre/lib/ there is no i386 folder, or any folder named after an architecture at all. Oh, and I worked with RXTX 2.2 and with Java8, but it was still fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Java Build Path -> Source -> Native library location -> Add your `rxtxso` and Comm jar file.
2. Java Build Path -> Add External JAR -> RXTXcomm.jar
3. Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> Click RXTXcomm.jar