# raspberry ttyUSB0 ERROR

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, fingerprint, rxtx

> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError thrown while loading
>   gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver thrown while loading
>   gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver Failed to connect on port: /dev/ttyUSB0
>   exception:  gnu.io.NoSuchPortException

I am using Java in Raspberry Pi and now I get an error while using the fingerprint sensor. The connection is USB-TTL.

The fingerprint sensor module is ZFM-20.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the native library to your JVM instance.

Install rxtx with :

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java
```

then start the app with a command line like the following:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar:. -jar appName.jar
```

If you are using eclipse you need to add a native library from the project preferences: 
[What is java.library.path , How to set in Eclipse IDE](https://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2013/04/what-is-javalibrarypath-how-to-set-in-Eclipse.html) .

See also this [similar thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164784/noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class#22165132) and [this tester app](https://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/rxtx-loopback-test-program1/) to test the port working correctly.